# Literal in front if condition

Tags: php, if-statement

Recently I saw programmer put literal in front of if condition

```
if ( -99 == $poll_id )
```

Why they did that? What is the difference with normal if e.g.:

```
if ( $poll_id == -99 )
```

Comment: how can you search for that question? 'null' is very specific word.

Comment: The style you describe is sometimes referred to as "yoda conditions". Searching on Stack Overflow with that term will quickly turn up some duplicates. It's not an easy thing to search for if you don't already know what it's called :)

Comment: yeah this is the first time i saw that term. you don't see that in code. thx for the reference. if I didn't ask, I won't get the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an idiom that is borrowed from C. It is called Yoda Conditions.

The idea behind the idiom is avoiding errors when you type one equal sign instead of two.

When you write

```
if ( x = 3 )
```

instead of

```
if ( x == 3 )
```

The code would compile, but work incorrectly.

If you get in the habit of turning the condition around, the code with a single equal sign would not compile.

Comment: Why did you post an answer instead of closing the question as a duplicate? The [linked questions list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/271561?lq=1) of the proposed duplicate lists 30 questions on the topic already.

Comment: I think my question is easier for searching